# C# WPF binding back and forth

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am new to binding in Wpf and I am probably overlooking something or going about it the wrong way.

[Map of my bindings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR1m4.png)

I have a class called Navigator(Controller) which bridges the View(UI) and Service(DataProvider). The only thing that the view and the service exchange is the DataModel(CurrentData) that the Navigator holds.

```
public class Navigator : INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Singleton class using Static I() and Instance() to get instance

```
        Binding myBinding = new Binding();
        myBinding.Source = Navigator.I;
        myBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("CurrentView");
        myBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        myBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(MasterWindow.ViewFrame, Frame.ContentProperty, myBinding);

        Binding myBinding2 = new Binding();
        myBinding2.Source = Navigator.I;
        myBinding2.Path = new PropertyPath("DataModel");
        myBinding2.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        myBinding2.BindsDirectlyToSource = true;
        myBinding2.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(CurrentView, Page.DataContextProperty, myBinding2);

        Binding myBinding11 = new Binding();
        myBinding11.Source = Navigator.I;
        myBinding11.Path = new PropertyPath("DataModel");
        myBinding11.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        myBinding11.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(ActiveService, UIService.ServiceModelProperty, myBinding11);

        Binding myBinding10 = new Binding();
        myBinding10.Source = Navigator.I.CurrentView;
        myBinding10.Path = new PropertyPath("Title");
        myBinding10.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
        myBinding10.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
        myBinding10.BindsDirectlyToSource = true;
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(MasterWindow, Window.TitleProperty, myBinding10);
```

My code behind bindings in the Navigator class

The title in the View(Page) is bound to the hosts, MainWindow Title.

> Where it breaks is when the CurrentView is changed, the Title is stuck
>   to the first view set.

One view displays Title depending on the datatype it is working with

```
<Page.Resources>
    <conv:DataTypeToString x:Key="ToString"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Page.Title>
    <Binding Path="DataType" Mode="OneWay" ConverterParameter="plural" Converter="{StaticResource ToString}"/>

</Page.Title>
```

Where it breaks is when the CurrentView is changed, the Title is stuck
to the first view set.

I am doing something wrong with Binding but can't find out what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the source of the binding like this:

```
myBinding10.Source = Navigator.I.CurrentView;
```

then the source for the binding is not "up to date" with whatever is held under the `CurrentView` property at any time, but rather the source is set to the value of that property at the moment when this line is executed. So even though the property value might change later on, the source will remain the same, and the title won't change. In order for the binding framework to also "track" changes to the `CurrentView` property (apart from the `Title` property) you should place it as part of the path, and not the source. So this should fix your problem:

```
myBinding10.Source = Navigator.I;
myBinding10.Path = new PropertyPath("CurrentView.Title");
```

Now whenever `CurrentView` changes or it's current value's `Title` changes, it will be reflected in your UI.